# Jena SDB IRI validation

Tags: uri, jena, uriencoding, iri

I have got several strange IRIs that I want to insert into Jena SDB, but I got some error messages:

1. http://example.org/text/1234#offset_2311_2317_10-12%
   the error message is:
   Code: 30/ILLEGAL_PERCENT_ENCODING in FRAGMENT: The host component a percent occurred without two following hexadecimal digits.
2. http://example.org/text/5678#offset_365_370_NDZ#2
   the error message is:
   Code: 0/ILLEGAL_CHARACTER in FRAGMENT: The character violates the grammar rules for URIs/IRIs.
3. http://example.org/text/7890#offset_8872_8878__"Fren
   the error message is:
   Code: 4/UNWISE_CHARACTER in FRAGMENT: The character matches no grammar rules of URIs/IRIs. These characters are permitted in RDF URI References, XML system identifiers, and XML Schema anyURIs.

The string 10-12%, NDZ#2 and _"Fren are extracted from plain text document and I have to attach it directly at the back of the IRIs. So my question is: are they valid IRIs? If not, considering I need to attach plain text at the back of IRIs, how can I convert them to valid IRIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 is wrong because it ends in % -- % is for hex encoding so it must be %xx

Encode the % -- use %25

2 is wrong because it has two fragments.  USe %23 is you mean # as a charcater, not as a fragment

3 has " in it.  Encode that.

Spaces are a bad idea as well.  Use %20.

Comment: How do we do encoding in jena? Will sparql query work on encoded string?